# Python pandas problem calculating percent in dataFrame and making it to a list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a problem calculating percent within a dataframe.
I have the following dataframe called dfGender:

```
      age     gender    impressions
    0 13-17   female    234561
    1 13-17   male      34574
    2 25-34   female    120665
    3 25-34   male      234560
    4 35-44   female    5134
    5 35-44   male      2405
    6 45-54   female    423
    7 45-54   male      324
```

Now I would like to make to have list of the total percent for all female and male impressions like this: [female%, male%].
My idea is to pivot_table with the following code:

```
df_genderSum = dfGender.pivot_table(columns='gender', values='impressions', aggfunc='sum')
```

Then calculating the total of them all:

```
df_genderSum['total'] = df_genderSum.sum(axis=1)
```

Then after this making the percent calculations through:

```
df_genderSum['female%'] = (df_genderSum['female']/df_genderSum['total'])*100
df_genderSum['male%'] = (df_genderSum['male']/df_genderSum['total'])*100
```

Now this gives me the desired correct calculations, altough I think it's a really messy code.
I have 2 questions:
1: Is there a simpler way to do this, where you get a dataframe only existing of:

```
gender      female%    male%
impressions "number"   "number"
```

2: How do i make it to a list. I was thinking of the following code.

```
list = df_genderSum.reset_index().values.tolist()
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
df.groupby('gender')['impressions'].apply(lambda x : (sum(x)/sum(df['impressions'])*100))


gender
female    57.0276
male      42.9724
```

and

```
df.groupby('gender')['impressions'].apply(lambda x : (sum(x)/sum(df['impressions'])*100)).to_list()


[57.02762682448004, 42.972373175519957]
```

If you want the exact dataframe that you asked for, save the above as "s" and do the following:

```
s=df.groupby('gender')['impressions'].apply(lambda x : (sum(x)/sum(df['impressions'])*100))

pd.DataFrame(s).T

gender          female       male
impressions  57.027627  42.972373
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
df_agg = df.drop(['age'], axis=1).groupby('gender').sum()
print(df_agg['impressions']/df_agg['impressions'].sum()*100)
```

Prints (can be different based on your data):

```
F    71.428571
M    28.571429
Name: impressions, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df_genderSum = df_gender.groupby('gender')['impressions'].sum() # same result as pivot_table
df_genderSum /= df_genderSum.sum() # percentage, inplace
# now it is a series, reshape as needed
df_genderSum = df_genderSum.to_frame().T
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this one :

```
(df.groupby('gender').sum()['impressions']/df['impressions'].sum()).to_frame(name = 'impressions').T
```